# Why was my appearance vs health answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

I've improved my previous (deleted) answer by including fewer pics and more text & links, and as it's "impossible" to undelete that because it was deleted by a moderator, I've [answered anew](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9030/is-physical-beauty-correlated-with-health/11015#11015).
I'm still wondering why my first answer was deleted, though, as [the questioner is not curious about apparent health, but actual health](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9030/is-physical-beauty-correlated-with-health/11015#comment36550_9039), a connection that I clearly showed (too much?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression was that you posted the images for shock value, not only to answer the question. That was what caused the immediate deletion. I also think that you're missing the point of the question, it is not about diseases that show visible symptoms that affect beauty, but about a more general correlation between beauty and health. So you answer also didn't actually answer the question.

I'm still not convinced that your now changed answer actually addresses the question that is asked, but I'll leave it to the community to deal with it. I've undeleted your old answer and deleted the duplicate one. In general, please flag for undeletion instead of duplicating your deleted answers.

Comment: I chose the most illustrative yet tasteful images I could find, and even commented that the girl in the first image was cute aside from the scabs. (The hip hop artist and DJ, [Leon Botha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leon_Botha), in the second image was even smiling.)
Thus I've clearly shown that disease (health flaw) can affect appearance (beauty). Appearance does not affect disease that much.

I tried to flag for undeletion, but then this site told me that undeletion was impossible for aforementioned reason. Please be more considerate and explain your actions in the future.